# Let $G'$ be the commutator subgroup of a group $G$. Prove that $G'$ is the intersection of all the $K\mathrel{\unlhd}G$ for which $G/K$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**The Statement of the Problem:**

Let $G'$ be the commutator subgroup of a group $G$. Prove that $G'$ is the intersection of all the $K\mathrel{\unlhd}G$ for which $G/K$ is abelian.

**Where I Am:**

I feel like the wording here is kind of confusing me a bit. I assume that what I want to prove here is $G' = \cap K$, i.e. $G' \subset \cap K$ and $\cap K \subset G'$. But I didn't take the "double-containment" approach; rather, I just observed the following:

\begin{align}
   (aK)(bK) & = (bK)(aK) & &\text{(because $G/K$ is abelian)} \\
   abK & = baK & & \text{(because $K$ is normal)} \\
   K & = b^{-1}a^{-1}baK & & \text{(multiplying both sides by $b^{-1}a^{-1}$)} \\
\ 
\end{align}
Clearly the RHS is in $K$, but the "intersection" thing is throwing me off. My choices of $a$ and $b$ were arbitrary, so certainly this proves that the RHS is also in the intersection of all normal $K$'s, right? Furthermore, since all of these statements are, as far as I can tell, "iff," this means that I don't have to prove the other direction of containment, right? Am I missing something here?

Comment: try this simpler situation: $G/K$ is abelian iff $G'\subseteq K$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have shown is that for all $a,b$ in $G$ the element $b^{-1}a^{-1}ba$ is an element of every  such  $K$.

This means that $G'$, which is the group generated by elements of the form $b^{-1}a^{-1}ba$, is a subset of $K$ for each such $K$, and whence of the intersection of all such $K$.

Yet, there is no guarantee there are no other elements in each such $K$. 
So the containment could be proper.

A way to exclude this is to show that $G'$ is a normal subgroup and $G/G'$ is abelian, that is $G'$ is in fact among the $K$ you consider.